# Where do I find Nmake for Windows XP

Tags: perl

Regarding BioPerl installation in Windows XP, I have installed Active Perl in Windows XP, and by using Perl Package Manager I have installed the BioPerl Repositories too. But I am not able to run the BioPerl yet.

While running the BioPerl program in emacs it is showing the following error:

```
 make -k
 'make' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I have tried to install Nmake for Windows but this error is showing.

> No webpage was found for the web address: http://download.microsoft.com/download/vc15/patch/1.52/w95/en-us/nmake15.exe

How could this be resolved?

Comment: Are you running this through cygwin? If not, try that. Additionally, what do you mean by running the program in emacs?

Comment: Just a reminder, make/nmake may be trying to trigger other build tools. You may find [Visual Studio Express handy](https://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express). Also, please answer the Cygwin question, it affects your solution.

Comment: Use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), you will find it much easier to work in and porting code is a dream. See also [Using PERL with Cygwin](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~jeffay/dirt/FAQ/cygwin-perl.html) and [How do I install perl libraries in cygwin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483574/how-do-i-install-perl-libraries-in-cygwin).

Comment: YES i am running through cygwin..
emacs is a perl editor.. @ soandos

Comment: i have also installed Visual Studio Express..but problem i not resolved..

Comment: You may want to investigate Strawberry Perl, which includes a full GCC toolchain and nmake and all those treats.  http://strawberryperl.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this: ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/Softlib/MSLFILES/Nmake15.exe 
It's a self-extracting zip containing the files NMAKE.ERR, NMAKE.EXE and README.TXT. You should put these somewhere on your PATH, e.g. C:\perl\bin\ . Since you mentioned ActiveState: I think that's where this installs to so you should have that folder.

Note: some while ago anonymous login to the above ftp server didn't work but it seems fixed now, just tried it myself.

Comment: i have tried ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/Softlib/MSLFILES/Nmake15.exe but it is showing following error
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ftp.microsoft.com.
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to ftp.microsoft.com

Comment: It seems MS has taken down permanently the http link you mentioned. But: the ftp link is working, at least every now and then... Right now it worked for me in Firefox, Chrome and with the ftp client of TotalCommander. Use "anonymous" as the user name and your email address as the password.

Comment: @meisl, Link doesn't work.